# ITextSharp PDf Issue in adding ASP UserControl & HTML Control to PdfPCell

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

Below is my Code,

.aspx:

```
<table border="0" width="100%" id="maintable" runat="server">
<tr>
<td style="width:90%;vertical-align:top;">
 <div id="content_left" runat="server"  style="margin-right:10px;
float:left;vertical-align:top;width:690px" ></div>
</td>
<td style="vertical-align:top;background-color:#eee;width:100px;">
<div id="content_right" runat="server" style="background-color:#eee;float:right;
width:300px;"></div>
</td>

</tr>
</table>
```

.aspx.cs:

```
  HtmlGenericControl aboutme_content = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
  aboutme.ID = "aboutme1";
  aboutme.Text= "ABOUT ME";
  content_left.Controls.Add(aboutme_content);
  PdfPTable table_left = new PdfPTable(1);
  PdfPCell cell_1 = new PdfPCell();
```

Now,my doubt is how will i add content_left to PdfPCell.Similarly,I have my usercontrol and want to add the same to another PDFPCell.I tried using PDFP.ADDElement(),But it didn't work out.

Comment: You are going to have to clarify your question. I think you're trying to parse HTML into PDF, if so, do a search on that and remember that iTextSharp has absolutely zero knowledge of ASP.Net, only HTML. Its your job to turn the former into the latter.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create `PDF` from the markup on the fly.

Please check the following Sample:

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.html;
using iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser;

protected void HTMLToPDF()
    {
        string strHTML = @"<div>Some html markup & text </div>";
        String htmlText = strHTML.ToString();
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "MyTestPDF.pdf", FileMode.Create));
        document.Open();
        iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker hw =
                     new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker(document);
        hw.Parse(new StringReader(htmlText));
        document.Close();
    }
```

Hope this helped you..!

**Update:**

Filling in `PDF Forms` with `iTextSharp`:

```
private void fillPdf() {
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AppendHeader(
      "Content-Disposition",
      "attachment;filename=itext_fill.pdf"
    );
    PdfReader r = new PdfReader(
      new RandomAccessFileOrArray(Request.MapPath("test_fill.pdf")), null
    );
    using (PdfStamper ps = new PdfStamper(r, Response.OutputStream)) {
      AcroFields af = ps.AcroFields;
      af.SetField("lname", lname.Text);
      af.SetField("fname", fname.Text);
      af.SetField("address", address.Text);
      af.SetField("zip", zip.Text);
      ps.FormFlattening = true;
    }
    Response.End();
  }
```

Comment: Obviously this doesn't help with the `runat="server"` parts of the op's code, does it?

Comment: @mkl i have CLEARLY mentioned as "SOME HTML Markup" and not for ASP.NET Markup controls..! And if you need to add table use "PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);" where '2' is the number of columns for the table and if need to add control use PDFStamper.